# Fanning out and summing results in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

The below is a mockup of something I'm trying to achieve in RxJS (summing resource counts by compliance status). It works, but is there a simpler way to write this?

```js
const { combineLatest, of, map, switchMap } = require('rxjs');

let rules$ = of(['one', 'two', 'three']); // in the real world, this comes from an HTTP call

let complianceTypes = [
  'COMPLIANT',
  'NON_COMPLIANT',
  'NOT_APPLICABLE',
  'INSUFFICIENT_DATA',
];

const getCountsForRule$ = () => of(1); // in the real world, this comes from an HTTP call

rules$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((rules) =>
      combineLatest(
        complianceTypes.map((complianceType) =>
          combineLatest(rules.map((rule) => getCountsForRule$(rule))).pipe(
            map((counts) => ({
              complianceType,
              count: counts.reduce((total, count) => count + total, 0),
            }))
          )
        )
      ).pipe(
        map((counts) =>
          counts.reduce(
            (acc, count) => ({
              ...acc,
              [count.complianceType]: count.count,
            }),
            {}
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((res) => console.log('Got result', { res }))
```

Comment: One thing is not clear to me. Is it correct to think that the function `getCountsForRule$` expects 2 parameters: "rule" and "complianceType"?

Comment: @Picci You're right, but it doesn't affect the functionality. `getCountsForRule$` returns an `Observable<number>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem right I would proceed like this.

First of all I would build a function that, given a rule, returns the counts for all compliance types in one shot, e.g.

```
const countForRule$ = (rule) => {
  // create an array of Observables that "execute" the query for each compliance type
  const counts$ = complianceTypes.map((complianceType) => {
    return getCountsForRule$(rule, complianceType).pipe(
      map((count) => ({ count, complianceType }))
    );
  });
  // Execute the queries in parallel using forkJoin
  return forkJoin(counts$);
};
```

Once we have this basic building block, we can create the complete stream like this

```
rules$
  .pipe(
    // rules is an array of rules and, with the from function
    // we turn it into a stream of rules
    concatMap(rules => from(rules)),
    // as soon as a rule is notified by upstream, we "execute" the query
    // for the counts of all compliance types
    concatMap((rule) => {
      return countForRule$(rule);
    }),
    // eventually we reduce all the values notified by upstream into a 
    // single result
    reduce((acc, val) => {
      console.log(val)
      val.forEach(countForType => {
        const count = countForType.count
        const type = countForType.complianceType
        acc[type] = acc[type] ? acc[type] + count : count
      })
      return acc;
    }, {})
  )
  .subscribe((res) => console.log('Got result', res));
```

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tkj3hg?file=index.ts) shows it.

I am not sure this is simpler than your solution. I think though it is more in line with a reactive style. Up to you to decide whether this considerations are valid or not.

Comment: Yes, that's a bit simpler. For one thing it does away with all the `combineLatest` statements I had in. Thanks!

Comment: I think the biggest thing for me here is seeing how I can change an Observable of an array into an Observable that emits each value of the array, thus allowing me to stay in an Observable context rather than having to switch back and forth as I had been doing. This was very helpful. Again, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can find something interesting in [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this perhaps strikes a balance between readability and composing observables?

```js
import { of
       , switchMap
       , merge
       , forkJoin
       , reduce
       } from 'rxjs';

const count$ = (rules, compliance) => {
  const rules$ = rules.map(() => of(1));
  return ( merge(...rules$)
         . pipe(reduce((t, n) => t + n, 0)));
}

( of(['one', 'two', 'three'])

. pipe( switchMap(rules =>
                    forkJoin({ COMPLIANT:         count$(rules, 'COMPLIANT')
                             , NON_COMPLIANT:     count$(rules, 'NON_COMPLIANT')
                             , NOT_APPLICABLE:    count$(rules, 'NOT_APPLICABLE')
                             , INSUFFICIENT_DATA: count$(rules, 'INSUFFICIENT_DATA')})))

. subscribe((res) => console.log(res)));
```

Not sure if that is what you were after but hope it helps.